# Execute spark tests locally instead of remote

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have imported databricks jars in my project and have databricks-connect configured to my remote db cluster.

When I run unit tests in Intellij, it starts running unit tests on remote machine. I want to disable this and whenever I get the spark session, it attempts to get session from my remote server. How do I make it run in my local machine? Is there any config I neet ot set it to not connect to the remote db cluster?

Thanks